# Quantum Error Correction implementation in Qiskit, OpenQASM or other languages based on Python

Tags: programming, qiskit, error-correction, resource-request, qasm

Where can we find example(s) of implementation code in a programming language of Quantum Error Correction, whether with the standard method of measurement or the automatic method without measurement (with control operators) ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is something you are looking for:

[Benchmarking near-term devices with quantum error correction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.11037.pdf) by James Wootton

Answer (score 1):

A nice place to look is always the qiskit textbook!

https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/error-correction-repetition-code.html

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOFEBzvs-VvrXTMy5Y2IqmSaUjfnhvBHR

Videos 13 14 and 15 are for QEC. But, you can watch the playlist for more reference